# Detect UITextField Secure Text Entry overwritten text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

When using `Secure Text Entry` in a `UITextField` the text is overwritten if I have entered a text, gone to another text field and coming back and start writing without pressing back.

Now, Im using the following to keep track of the entered text:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
}
```

But in the case above, the event doesnt track that the textfield has been cleared thus I cannot always rely on the string `text`

Any good tips?

Comment: when you enter text in textfield that time always clear textfield.

Comment: try to clear textfield using 
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;

Comment: @Darji I'm using `Secure Text Entry` which hides my text as intented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I simply changed the logic as track textfield changes with this event instead:

`[textField addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];`

`textFieldDidChange`will be called each time the text changes.

Comment: A true life saver. Thanks mate. I really appreciate that. :)

Answer (score 0):

i can tell you an easy way to do it in the xcode itself.

[image: Select <code>Clear when editing begins</code> checkbox]

Select `Clear when editing begins` checkbox

[image: Select <code>Secure</code> checkbox]

Select `Secure` checkbox

Comment: This wont work - the text is not correct in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`